# sort array of strings depending on last occurance after .?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array containing a list of filenames that I want to sort by extension. Folders first then files sorted by extension :

Consider the code below:

```
    $arr = array("noext","world.b","hello.a","test.z","lol.f");
```

Is there anyway how can I sort the array above depending on the extension to get something like the following :

```
    noext
    hello.a
    world.b
    lol.f
    test.z
```

I know I could use something like usort with a comparing function. But I have no idea how can I do it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use usort:

```
<?php
$arr = array("noext","world.b","hello.a","test.z","lol.f");
usort($arr, function($s1, $s2) {
  $ext1 = pathinfo($s1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $ext2 = pathinfo($s2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  return strcmp($ext1, $ext2);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! this did exactly what I wanted, you saved my day! you deserve a beer ;)

Comment: :) If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).